# print multiple output one by one from index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, sqlite

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\wh112\Desktop\BRAIN.sqlite')
df1 = pd.read_sql('select * from PRONOUN',connection)
df2 = pd.read_sql('select * from VERB',connection)
df3 = pd.read_sql('select * from QUESTIONS',connection)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

def word_list(text):
return list(filter(None, re.split('\W+', text)))


session = raw_input("Test on me!")
feedback = session
print(word_list(feedback))

dff = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':[feedback]})
dff['1'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[0]
dff['2'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
dff['3'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[2]

for pts1 in dff['1']:
  pts1 = df.columns[df.isin([pts1]).any()]
for pts2 in dff['2']:
 pts2 = df.columns[df.isin([pts2]).any()]
for pts3 in dff['3']:
 pts3 = df.columns[df.isin([pts3]).any()]
```

Now the Topic is on:

```
 pts1 = df.columns[df.isin([pts1]).any()]
```

when I am working with this to find any match from database string; multiple match shows together on output. like this:

```
Index([u'auxiliary_verbfirst_person_singular_pronounnon_wh_type'])
```

But I want them to be one by one like:

```
Index([u'auxiliary_verb, first_person_singular_pronoun,non_wh_type'])
```

is there any way to do this, can you help me, please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ andrew_reece I've done it dear. please, have a review now. Thank You :)

Comment: @wh112 I am unable to replicate the problem in python 3.x

Comment: @ chris I'm on python 2.7 dear . . . :( :/